# Separate every ascii character when saving it into a file

Tags: c, compression, txt

So I want to save ascii characters into a txt file or anything alike
it's just a compression method that I want to do to save space so there are no separators for each character
but the thing is it turns into something else with a different encoding with ascii

[This is what it looks like with whitespaces. This is what I want to happen except without the spaces][1]

[And this is what it looks like without the whitespace][2]

this is the function that tries to decompress it

```
    int i, j=0, k=0, ch, finaldec=0;
    char temp[8], finalcode[1000], tempc;

    for (i=count; i>=0; i--){
        j++;
        temp[j]=huffmanCode[i];
        if (temp[j]=='1'){
            finaldec+=pow(2, j);

        }
        if (j==7){
            finalcode[k]=finaldec;
            printf("%c ", finalcode[k]);
            finaldec=0;
            k++;
            j=0;
        }
    }
    FILE *ff;
    ff = fopen("text_compress.txt", "w+");
    for (i=0; i<k; i++)
        fprintf(ff, "%c ", finalcode[i]);
    fclose(ff);
}
```

What this funtion does is just it takes a series of 1 and 0 then in each byte it will convert it into an ascii character

What am I supposed to do to save the ascii properly?
use a different file extension or is there some invisible separator like '\0'?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3gKI.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8W3e.png

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the contents of `finalcode` are not valid ASCII characters. Notepad is probably interpreting some of these bytes as UTF-encoded characters and whether you have spaces or not is likely just changing that interpretation.

If you're expecting the output to be some valid ASCII text then it would seem there's probably some issue with your compression or decompression function (although it's tough to know for sure without seeing how `HuffmanCode` is being populated).

Comment: If I do this https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3gKI.png
and adjust accordingly, the compression and decompression works fine
but the compressed file size would be larger than the decompressed
that's why I somehow need to remove the whitespaces in between
and i don't have any other idea than converting a byte to decimal to ascii